# Checkbox is not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am creating a form in which I have specified some EditText and some TextView . At last I have specified a Checkbox like this:

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sendAsSMS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send As SMS"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                />
```

But this checkbox is not getting displayed in the layout when the app is running. What is going wrong here. 
My full layout.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.schoolcounter.ui.activity.teacher.AddHomeworkActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addHomeworkForm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selectClassLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/select_class"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:text="@string/select_class"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                android:id="@+id/select_class_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="@string/select_class"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selectSectionLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/select_section"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:text="@string/select_section"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                android:id="@+id/select_section_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="@string/select_section"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selectSubjectLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/select_subject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:text="@string/select_subject"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                android:id="@+id/select_subject_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="@string/select_subject"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/uploadedDateLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_uploaded_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:text="@string/text_uploaded_date"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUploadedDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/completionDateLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_completion_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:text="@string/text_completion_date"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextCompletionDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_Homework"
                android:text="@string/text_homework"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextHomeworkText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="74dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sendAsSMS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send As SMS"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uploadHomeworkButton"
                style="@style/button_style_corners"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/text_upload"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the width attribute value of EditText 'editTextHomeworkText' in

> ```
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/textView_Homework"
>             android:text="@string/text_homework"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
>             android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
>             android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/editTextHomeworkText"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="74dp"
>             android:ems="10"
>             android:inputType="textMultiLine"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
>
>         <CheckBox
>             android:id="@+id/sendAsSMS"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Send As SMS"
>             android:checked="false"
>             android:textSize="16sp"
>
>             />
>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
> ```

Since you assigned the width value as 'match_parent' all the remaining space is covered by EditText only. Here either you can change the value to 'wrap_content' or do it like

> ```
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
> ```